Why my scene gets dark when I enable Vulkan preview in Unreal Engine 5.3.2?
I'm making a VR build for Meta Quest 3 on Unreal Engine 5.3.2. I have a scene with baked light which looks fine, like this:

But when I turn on the Vulkan Mobile Preview, the scene turns dark, with no bake or light, like this:

I've already made a lot of changes on project settings to test if the problem persists, but nothing seams to solve it, always the same thing. Please someone can help me with this?
I've tried to enable mobile HDR but when I did this the build didn't open on Quest 3, also verified the Nvidia drives and all are up to date. it seams like project settings config, but nothing actually change this, and the settings are all according to Meta XR Project Setup Tool. I just want to bake a scene and when enable Vulkan preview, the light to remain the same, just the little diference of quality expected from Vulkan.

Try changing your point lights' mobility to movable.
